# ec2 ip pública no se puede acceder a este sitio web

Tags: nodejs, servidor, aws, ec2

estoy intentando correr una instancia en `ec2` de `aws` para subir un proyecto de laravel, es la **primera vez** que utilizo `aws` y configuro un servidor en general, mi proyecto en laravel se conecta a un servidor de `node`, entonces como veo que será más fácil configurar laravel me fuí a configurar node primero, buscando en internet encontré el siguiente [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vf210p2tJg) que conecta una aplicación de `node` con `mongodb` sencilla, entonces para hacer las cosas fáciles tomé los archivos de su repositorio.

Ok, hasta el punto en que instala node y sube el archivo `app.js` a la instancia voy bien, pero cuando corro `app.js`, aunque no me da error en consola, cuando tengo que abrir el servidor no pasa nada, sospecho que tiene que ver con las `reglas de seguridad`, pero no soy muy bueno en redes.

Esto es lo que me arroja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las reglas de seguridad de entrada y salida respectivamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencione antes, no soy mucho de redes y esa parte me confunde un poco, `app.js` corre en el puerto `8000`, en el servidor hace una redirección del puerto `800` al `80`, eso no se si es necesario para mi aplicación, ya que eso lo conecto con laravel, igual yo se lo coloque, si creen que no es necesario me podrían comentar como quitar esa redirección por favor, pero bueno, continuando con el problema.

En el video, cuando se crea la instancia en el paso 6 agrega las reglas, pero ya la interfaz es muy distinta, el coloca esto que no supe adaptar a mi instancia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me podrian ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Son muchas cosas en juego para dar una respuesta certera. Mediante que haces la redireccion de puertos? tu servidor de nodejs corre por el puerto 8000? usas http o https para inicializarlo? las reglas que muestras son las del securityGroup asociado a la instancia EC2?

Comment: Hola @Pipe, gracias por comentar, la redirección la hago con el siguiente comando `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000`, sí, el puerto corre por el puerto `8000`, realmente utilice un proyecto de prueba en github que no revise demasiado, no se si usa http o https y finalmente sí, es el grupo de seguridad de la instancoa EC2, pero ya lo solucione, en un momento publico mi solución

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lo conseguí, si alguien sabe de redes mejor que yo que explique mejor esto si puede, pero segun entiendo las reglas de entrada son los puertos por los que será accesible el contenido del servidor, siempre y cuando la aplicación que se utilice corra en ese puerto.

##### Ejemplo

> Mi archivo `app.js` despliega un servidor en el puerto `8080`, y en mi instancia de ec2 cuento con una regla de entrada al puerto `80`, al momento ejecutar `node app.js` lo que pasara es que mi servidor dentro de la instacia correra, pero no sera accesible publicamente, para ello me dirijo a crear una nueva regla de entrada al puerto `8080` y una ves finalizado ya podré acceder desde `<IPv4 de mi instacia>:8080`, y al recargar la página funcionaria

Como dato importante, si acaso no lo sabes el puerto `80` es el puerto por defecto, así que si tu aplicacion corre en ese puerto y tienes su respectiba regla de entrada, bastaría con acceder a la ruta `IPv4 publica` de tu instancia.

Ahora bien, al momento de iniciar el servidor pues lo que debia agregar la regla de entrada para el puerto 80, que yo ya poseía. Aparte de eso, seguí los pasos del siguiente [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edXbZee_A4A).

El tutorial que esta vez seguí se diferencia en que instala todo desde el `root` de la  instancia al utilizar el comando `sudo su`, y dentro de la carpeta `etc/yum.repos.d/` crea el proyecto, aunque sinceramente la ubicación del proyecto no es tan relevante, bien se podría crear el proyecto en `/home`.

Algo que sinceramente no se si afecto es que copie la Dirección IPv4 pública de la instancia y ya ahí me cargo, pero creo que talvez habia escrito un numero de mas cuando estaba haciendo las ultimas pruebas, pero por si acaso asegurarse de estar conectados a la dirección correcta.

Finalmente, aveces tube unos cuantos problemas por correr la aplicación, marcandome un error por el puerto, pero basicamente este surgia porque abría el puerto desde las reglas de salida o algo así, solo me pasaba cuando hacia pruebas con las reglas de salida, o aveces abría ese puerto pero olvidaba cerrarlo, y no me daba cuenta, y por eso no podía correr en el mismo puerto, pero, lo que hacia era reiniciar la instancia, supongo que habrá un comando para tumbar un puerto, pero fue la opción mas rapida que se me ocurrio.